# DBSCAN implementation in node.js

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, dbscan

I am using density-clustering (https://www.npmjs.com/package/density-clustering).

I have an array of 4000 location points - [[long,nat],...]

```
var clustering = require('density-clustering');
var dbscan = new clustering.DBSCAN();
var clusters = dbscan.run(dataset, 50000, 600);
```

No matter what values do I provide to "dbscan.run", cluster always returns an array containing [1,2,3,4....4000] value. I.e. for X data points in dataset, I get X clusters.

Comment: Can you make a minimum example using a subset of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/density-clustering#examples) for the library, the return value of the `dbscan.run()` call is a list of lists of indexes into your original `dataset` (which makes a lot of sense).

To get your clusters from those, you'd have to map them back using your original dataset:

```
const clusters = dbscan.run(dataset, ...);
// clusters is now [[id, id, id], [id, id, id], ...]
const coordinates = clusters.map(clu => clu.map(index => dataset[index]));
// coordinates is now [[[lat, lon], [lat, lon], [lat, lon]], ...]
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. Problem I am facing is - for X data points in dataset, I get X clusters.